# Is there a way to extract the color info of a pixel on the screen? - React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get the color of a pixel at a certain coordinate on the screen in React Native. Currently I only found libraries supporting getting color information at a coordinate in an image, but I'd like to access pixel information without taking a screenshot first.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what platform you're attempting this on. Also, is this a pixel that belongs to your app (ie in your app's views) or is this something *outside* your app (like the way Digital Color Meter works on macOS)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! It's on iOS, but preferrably on both plattforms. The pixel belongs to the app.